Fix User Authentication in Node.js
I am making a login system in mern stack, i am using jwt token based login system in the backend. In the provided code i am querying database for every page user requests to check wheather user is present in database. I don't want to run database query for every request how can i make this better and save user information in token and authenticate user with token. Will this be a good idea?, i am a beginner. Forget 2fa code in Login Controller.
// Login Controller
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) =\> {
const { email, password } = req.body;

// Validation
if (!email || !password) {
res.status(400);
throw new Error("Email and Password is Required");
}

// check if user exist
const user = await userModel.findOne({ email });
if (!user) {
res.status(400);
throw new Error("User does not Exist. Please Signup");
}

// check if password matches
const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

if (!isPasswordMatch) {
res.status(400);
throw new Error("Invalid Email or Password");
}

// Trigger 2FA for Unknown userAgent
const ua = parser(req.headers\["user-agent"\]);
const thisUserAgent = ua.ua;
console.log(thisUserAgent);

const allowedAgent = user.userAgent.includes(thisUserAgent);

if(!allowedAgent){
// generate 6 digit code
const loginCode = Math.floor(Math.random() \* (999999 - 100000 + 1)) + 100000;
console.log(loginCode);

    // encrypt login code before saving into db
    const encryptedLoginCode = cryptr.encrypt(loginCode.toString());
    
    // delete token if it exist in db
    const userToken = await tokenModel.findOne({ userID: user._id});
    
    if(userToken){
      await userToken.deleteOne();
    }
    
    // save token to db
    await new tokenModel({
      userID: user._id,
      loginToken: encryptedLoginCode,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
      expiresAt: Date.now() + 60 * ( 60 * 1000 ),
    
    }).save();
    
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("New browser or device detected");

}

// Generate Token
const token = generateToken(user.\_id);

if (user && isPasswordMatch) {
// Send HTTP-Only Cookie
res.cookie("token", token, {
httpOnly: true,
expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 \* 86400), // 1 day
sameSite: "none",
secure: true,
});

    // sending user data after login
    const { _id, name, email, phone, bio, image, role, isVerified } = user;
    
    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ _id, name, email, phone, bio, image, role, isVerified, token }); // attaching token into request

}
else{
res.status(500);
throw new Error("Something went wrong Please try again")
}
});


// Auth Middleware
const auth = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) =\>{
try {

        const token = req.cookies.token;
    
        // check if token is empty
        if(!token){
            res.status(401);
            throw new Error("No Token Found, Please Login");
        }
    
        // Verify Token
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET); // we can now get the user data associated with this token
    
        // Get user id from token
        const user = await userModel.findById(verified.id).select("-password"); // omiting password from sending to client
    
        // check if uset not found
        if(!user){
            res.status(404);
            throw new Error("User Not Found")
        }
    
    
        // if user is suspended
        if(user.role === "suspended"){
            res.status(400);
            throw new Error("User Suspended please contact support");
        }
    
        // if everything is fine
        req.user = user;
        next();
    
    
    } catch (error) {
        // when a user is not authorized
        console.log(error);
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("Not Authorized. Please Login")
    }

});

// Logout Controller
const logoutUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res)=\>{
res.cookie("token", "", {
httpOnly: true,
expires: new Date(0), // expires immediately
sameSite: "none",
secure: true,
});

    return res.json({ msg: "Logged Out"})

})


I suggest using an existing authentication method like OAuth or Keycloak. Building your own authentication can be frustrating, especially if you're a beginner. There are many factors to consider when securing your software, which can be overwhelming.
In response to your question: It's acceptable to check the database on every authentication attempt. Verifying if the user exists while navigating between pages is necessary; otherwise, you'd only check during login. Perhaps the concept of "Authentication and Refresh" tokens is what you're seeking

I have a my own small CRM project going though its small but i want to make sure that i  use best security practices like any other application out there. Which would you prefer to use in this scenario OAuth or Keycloack or using both. I have seen applications that uses jwt with oauth

I would recommend OAuth. It's widely used, not overly complicated to learn its functionalities, and there are plenty of examples and boilerplates available.

Thanks for the answere I will lookup for this.
